# OpenWRT. Makefile target pattern contains no '%'

Tags: makefile, openwrt

I'm trying to compile OpenWRT package. Already compile toolchain. From [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Error-Messages.html) I know it can be when use static pattern rules, but I don't. I checked the whole file for syntax errors - everything is fine (maybe I missed something).

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 Server
g++: 9.3.0
OpenWRT: 19.07.7

```sh
wiha@osboxes:~/source$ ./scripts/feeds update mypackage
Updating feed 'mypackage' from '\home\wiha\package_src\package' ...
Create index file './feeds/mypackage.index' 
/home/wiha/source/feeds/mypackage.tmp/info/.files-packageinfo.mk:1: *** target pattern contains no '%'.  Stop.
```

Makefile:

```
include $(TOPDIR)/rules.mk

PKG_NAME:=mypackage
PKG_VERSION:=0.1
PKG_RELEASE:=1

SOURCE_DIR:=../../..

include $(INCLUDE_DIR)/package.mk

define Package/mypackage
    SECTION:=mypackage
    CATEGORY:=Network
    TITLE:=The router`s agent
    DEPENDS:=+libopenssl +libjson-c +libcurl
    URL:=https://www.example.com
endef

define Build/Prepare
    mkdir -p $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)

    # copy source files
    $(CP) -r $(SOURCE_DIR)/src $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/src
    $(CP) $(SOURCE_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)

    rm -f $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/CMakeCache.txt
    rm -fR $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/CMakeFiles
    rm -f $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/Makefile
    rm -f $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/cmake_install.cmake
    rm -f $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/progress.make
endef

define Build/Configure
    IN_OPENWRT=1 \
    AR="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)ar" \
    AS="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CC) -c $(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
    LD="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)ld" \
    NM="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)nm" \
    CC="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CC)" \
    GCC="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CC)" \
    CXX="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)g++" \
    RANLIB="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)ranlib" \
    STRIP="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)strip" \
    OBJCOPY="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)objcopy" \
    OBJDUMP="$(TOOLCHAIN_DIR)/bin/$(TARGET_CROSS)objdump" \
    TARGET_CPPFLAGS="$(TARGET_CPPFLAGS)" \
    TARGET_CFLAGS="$(TARGET_CFLAGS)" \
    TARGET_LDFLAGS="$(TARGET_LDFLAGS)" \
    cmake $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/CMakeLists.txt
endef

define Build/Compile
    $(MAKE) -C $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)
    $(STRIP) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/mypackage
endef

define Package/mypackage/install
    $(CP) $(SOURCE_DIR)/files/* $(1)/

    $(INSTALL_DIR) $(1)/usr/bin
    $(INSTALL_BIN) $(PKG_BUILD_DIR)/mypackage $(1)/usr/bin/
endef

$(eval $(call BuildPackage,mypackage))
```

.files-packageinfo.mk:

```
$(eval $(call PackageDir,Makefile:$(eval $(call BuildPackage,mypackage)),Makefile:$(eval $(call BuildPackage,mypackage)),))
```

Comment: As the error message says, the issue is not in `Makefile` it's in `/home/wiha/source/feeds/mypackage.tmp/info/.files-packageinfo.mk` (line 1).  So you'll have to go look at what that file contains to figure out the problem.

Comment: @MadScientist I added this file to question

Comment: It was my bad. I made changes in Makefile and didn't remove old feed files.